# JavaFX shrink buttons with window resizing

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `GridPane` with nine square buttons and I want it to be resizable. As it is, it does grow bigger when I make the window bigger, but when I make the window smaller, the buttons don't change size so the window looks like this:

[image]

Here's my .fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<HBox prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
    <children>
        <GridPane fx:id="boardGridPane" layoutX="50" layoutY="25" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700" prefWidth="700" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="33.3" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="33.3" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="button00" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  />
                <Button fx:id="button01" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                <Button fx:id="button02" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
                <Button fx:id="button10" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <Button fx:id="button11" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <Button fx:id="button12" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <Button fx:id="button20" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <Button fx:id="button21" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <Button fx:id="button22" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            </children>
        </GridPane>
        <VBox fx:id="menuVBox" layoutX="786.0" layoutY="336.0" prefHeight="77.0" prefWidth="178.0">
            <children>
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Hot Seat Mode" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Easy Bot Mode" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Hard Bot Mode" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Statistics" />
                <TextArea fx:id="menuTextArea"/>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: Are you using `SceneBuilder`?

Comment: @Sedrick do you mean the visual layout tool? Then I am, but I'd rather edit the fxml file or code, I don't really get what does this visual editor have to do with the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are editing the `FXML` yourself, remove `minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"` from the `<GridPane>` tag.

In `SceneBuilder` you are using `USE_PRE_SIZE` on the `GridPane`:

[image]

Change the values to `USE_COMPUTER_SIZE`:

[image]